# Linux - mount on access

Tags: linux, ssh, mount

Is it possible to automatically mount a linux server over ssh (I use `sshfs`) in the time I access the directory, where it is usually mounted?

Currently I always have to open the terminal and manually mount the server to specific directory (that's always in the same location) and I would like it to be mounted automatically, immediately after I access (read) the directory or some of its subdirectories. I don't want to use fstab because then I'd have to enter credentials for the server every time after boot.

How would you do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, there are "mount on first access" methods, such as autofs4, parts of which are also available in systemd. (Just mark a fstab entry as `x-systemd.automount` in the options field.) I wouldn't be surprised if there also was a FUSE-based automount implementation.

However, for any automount method to work, it must be possible to mount the filesystem completely automatically, with *no* interactive password prompts. (That is, you will have to use SSH public-key authentication or similar.)

In other words, as long as you cannot automate this on *boot* (as you said "I'd have to enter credentials … every time after boot"), then you won't be able to automate it on access either.

Exception: GNOME and KDE programs can access remote servers in another way – if you try to use a `sftp://…` URL in them, they'll connect to the server themselves without using a kernel mount. Since the entire connection is made within the same graphical session, they can prompt for password just fine.